# Is it possible to visualise the mapper results in a map-reduce process?

Tags: python, hadoop, dictionary, cloudera, reduce

In the file part-00000 we can find the result of all the process (map+reduce), but i would like to see the result of the firt step (mapping) then the whole results.

I'm working on Hadoop Cloudera with python map-reduce scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to output the result of map or process of map, one solution is to output result of map to stderr.
ex:
if python:

```
import sys
print >> sys.stderr, "result of map"
```

if shell:

```
echo -e "result of map" >&2
```

then ,you can see what result of map is in hadoop job log

Comment: Yes that's what i want, but i didn't find the hadoop job log

Comment: As default, log will be printed in command window, and you can find tracking url, open it in browser, you'll get log including sys.stdout, sys.stderr, syslog

Answer (score 0):

If that's just for initial analysis purpose to understand the data and key then you probably would like to set the Reducer count to 0 and get the map's output.
-D mapred.reduce.tasks =0 is a way in java, explore the same for Python.